# long exact sequence of representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, exact-sequence, equivariant-maps

Let $G$ be a group and $V_1,V_2 $ be $G$-representations. Are the ${\rm Ext}^i(V_1,V_2)$ $G$-representations as well?

Once established this, suppose I have a short exact sequence $$0\to V_1\to V_2\to V_3\to 0$$
is the long exact sequence in cohomology obtained applying ${\rm Hom}(V,-) $ for another $G$-representation $V$ an exact sequence of representations as well?

Comment: Have you thought about this for $i=0$?

Comment: For i=0 it is simpler as I see the elements of the Hom as maps of representations and hence I know how to put an action on it

Comment: The answer is no, there is no natural action of $G$ on the Ext groups. When you write Hom, you have to be clear whether you mean homorphisms of vector spaces or of  $G$-modules. There is a natural action of $G$ on the space ${\rm Hom}(V_1,V_2)$ of vector space homomorphisms, and the fixed points of thsi action are precisely the $G$-homomorphisms, often written as ${\ \rm Hom}_G(V_1,V_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\operatorname{Ext}_G^i(V_1, V_2)$ as a $G$-module with the trivial action (every element of $G$ acts as the identity).